# how to take an average of a 2x2 pixel block?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image and I have to take the average of the color of 2x2 pixel.

*take the average color of a 2x2 pixel block, then compute the distance between the colors in the image and the colors available for our use.*

I have no idea what taking the average of 2x2 pixel block means. How to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I would assume it means take the intensity values of the 4 pixels in a 2x2 square and average them?

Comment: How do I extract those 4 pixels? Sorry we started image processing this week, so I don't know a lot of stuff.

Comment: Are these blocks meant to overlap, as in a sliding window, or are they non-overlapping blocks? The naive way to extract a submatrix is to use `M(i:i+2,j:j+2)`, but there are more efficient methods like `conv2` if the process is to be repeated over the whole image.

Comment: It is an image that are non-overlapping blocks and has even number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can process non-overlapping blocks of an image using [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)

```
Im = imread('coins.png');                            %// example image

fun = @(block_struct) mean( block_struct.data(:) );  %// anonymous function to get average of a block
B = blockproc(Im,[2 2],fun);                         %// process 2 by 2  blocks
imshow(B,[]);                                        %// show resulting image
```

Answer (score 2):

One other method I can suggest is to use combination of [`colfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) with the `'sliding'` flag and [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) as the function to operate on.  The `'distinct'` flag is what you actually need to use, but if you see the conversation between myself and @eigenchris, we couldn't get it to work.  Still, eigenchris has shown that this is 300x faster than `blockproc`.

Therefore, assuming your image is stored in `im`, you can simply do:

```
out = uint8(colfilt(im, [2 2], 'sliding', @mean));
out2 = out(1:2:end,1:2:end);
```

The reason why you would need to subsample the results is because when we apply a `sliding` option, you have overlapping blocks processing the image at a time.  Because you want **distinct** blocks, you only need 1/4 of the image because you have decomposed the image into 2 x 2 blocks.  Within a 2 x 2 block, if you did the sliding option, you would have three other results that are not required, and so doing the subsampling above by a factor of two eliminates those three other blocks that give results.

Note that you'll need to cast the result as the output will be of type `double`.

---

Going with the discussion between myself and eigenchris, you can replace `colfilt` with the canonical [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) to replicate the first line of the above code.  I managed to get an 8x speedup on my machine when comparing the two together.  Therefore:

```
out = imfilter(im, [0.25 0.25; 0.25 0.25], 'replicate');
out2 = out(1:2:end,1:2:end);
```

In terms of speedup, I wrapped each call in an anonymous function, then used [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) to time the functions:

```
>> f = @() uint8(colfilt(im, [2 2], 'sliding', @mean));
>> g = @() imfilter(im, [0.25 0.25; 0.25 0.25], 'replicate');
>> T = timeit(f);
>> T2 = timeit(g);
>> T/T2

ans = 

7.5421
```

As you can see, there is roughly a 8x speedup over `colfilt`... most likely because it's calling `im2col` and `col2im` under the hood.

Comment: This will be much faster if it works, but I get an error when I use the `'distinct'` option rather than the `'sliding'` option. The documentation for `colfilt` says that "`fun` must return a matrix the same size as the temporary matrix" in the case of `'distinct'`. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: @eigenchris - Huh... that's what I get when I don't test code lol.  I'll have to investigate and get back to you.  Thanks for the bug spot!

Comment: The `'sliding'` version is still 300x faster than `blockproc`. One hacky way to get the same result is using `'sliding'` and down-sampling it using `out2 = out(1:2:end,1:2:end)`.

Comment: Let's do that.  I can't figure out why the **** `distinct` isn't working.

Comment: It seems to not like returning scalars for some reason.... a function like `@(x) 2*x` works fine. I guess the MATLAB developers didn't make `colfilt` as flexible as we'd like.

Comment: @eigenchris - No kidding.  I'm kind of angry that we can't get it to operate on vectors... but eh.  BTW, thank you for the bug fixes.  I'd give you more than +1 on your answer if I could!

Comment: Yeah, it is very odd. Knowing that `colfilt` exists is its own reward, though. :P

Comment: @eigenchris - Heh :)  On a similar token, one could use `imfilter` and also subsample the image.  Have you tried replacing `colfilt` with `imfilter` with an average kernel of `0.25*ones(2,2)`?  I wonder how comparable this would be to `colfilt`.

Comment: @eigenchris - Heh... just ran my own test.  `imfilter` is faster... by about 8x more than `colfilt`.  This is probably because `imfilter` uses Intel Integrated Performance Primitives for speedup.  I wrapped the `colfilt` and `imfilter` calls in an anonymous function and used `timeit`.  I got `0.0058` for `colfilt` and `7.7134e-04` for `imfilter`.

Comment: Yup, even faster. :) I think the fact that `colfilt` calls `im2col` and `col2im` inside also causes some additional slowdown.

Comment: @eigenchris - Yeah I just took a look at the source.  I think I'll modify my answer to include `imfilter` as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Using loops:** (another method, just for knowing)

```
A = imread('cameraman.tif');

i = 1; j = 1;
[rows, cols] = size(A);
C(rows/2,cols/2) = 0;
for x = 1:2:rows
    for y = 1:2:cols
        block = [A(x,y),A(x+1,y),A(x,y+1),A(x+1,y+1)];
        C(i,j) = mean(block(:));
        j = j+1;
    end
    i = i+1;
    j = 1;
end
C = uint8(C);

figure;
imshow(A);                          %// show original image
figure;   
imshow(C);                          %// show resulting image
```